# Visual Studio Code doesn't make a new project, when using ng new

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

So I've added the library in path again but when I enter `ng new Colorizer`, I get a pop-up from Windows asking me how I want to open this file. I just need to make a new project, been trying for hours. Searching on Google was mostly useless.

Anyway, when I open it with Visual Studio Code, it opens up a file containing this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

// Provide a title to the process in `ps`.
// Due to an obscure Mac bug, do not start this title with any symbol.
process.title = 'ng';

const CliConfig = require('../models/config').CliConfig;
const Version = require('../upgrade/version').Version;

const fs = require('fs');
const findUp = require('../utilities/find-up').findUp;
const packageJson = require('../package.json');
const path = require('path');
const resolve = require('resolve');
const stripIndents = require('common-tags').stripIndents;
const yellow = require('chalk').yellow;
const SemVer = require('semver').SemVer;
const events = require('events');


function _fromPackageJson(cwd) {
  cwd = cwd || process.cwd();

  do {
    const packageJsonPath = path.join(cwd, 'node_modules/@angular/cli/package.json');
    if (fs.existsSync(packageJsonPath)) {
      const content = fs.readFileSync(packageJsonPath, 'utf-8');
      if (content) {
        const json = JSON.parse(content);
        if (json['version']) {
          return new SemVer(json['version']);
        }
      }
    }

    // Check the parent.
    cwd = path.dirname(cwd);
  } while (cwd != path.dirname(cwd));

  return null;
}


// Check if we need to profile this CLI run.
let profiler = null;
if (process.env['NG_CLI_PROFILING']) {
  profiler = require('v8-profiler');
  profiler.startProfiling();
  function exitHandler(options, err) {
    if (options.cleanup) {
      const cpuProfile = profiler.stopProfiling();
      fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), process.env.NG_CLI_PROFILING) + '.cpuprofile',
        JSON.stringify(cpuProfile));
    }

    if (options.exit) {
      process.exit();
    }
  }

  process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null, { cleanup: true }));
  process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.bind(null, { exit: true }));
  process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler.bind(null, { exit: true }));
}


// Show the warnings due to package and version deprecation.
const version = new SemVer(process.version);
if (version.compare(new SemVer('6.9.0')) < 0
    && CliConfig.fromGlobal().get('warnings.nodeDeprecation')) {
  process.stderr.write(yellow(stripIndents`
    You are running version ${version.version} of Node, which will not be supported in future
    versions of the CLI. The official Node version that will be supported is 6.9 and greater.

    To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.nodeDeprecation=false".
  `));
}


if (require('../package.json')['name'] == 'angular-cli'
  && CliConfig.fromGlobal().get('warnings.packageDeprecation')) {
  process.stderr.write(yellow(stripIndents`
    As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release,
    which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be officially deprecated shortly after.

    To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.packageDeprecation=false".
  `));
}

const packageJsonProjectPath = findUp('package.json', process.cwd(), true);
if (packageJsonProjectPath && fs.existsSync(packageJsonProjectPath)) {
  const packageJsonProject = require(packageJsonProjectPath);
  const deps = packageJsonProject['dependencies'] || {};
  const devDeps = packageJsonProject['devDependencies'] || {};
  const hasOldDep = !!deps['angular-cli'];
  const hasDep = !!deps['@angular/cli'];
  const hasOldDevDep = !!devDeps['angular-cli'];
  const hasDevDep = !!devDeps['@angular/cli'];

  if (hasOldDep || hasOldDevDep || !(hasDevDep || hasDep)) {
    const warnings = [
      'Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.',
      ''
    ];

    if (hasOldDep || hasOldDevDep) {
      warnings.push(
        'The package "angular-cli" has been deprecated and renamed to "@angular/cli".',
        '');
    }

    warnings.push('Please take the following steps to avoid issues:');

    if (hasOldDep) {
      warnings.push('"npm uninstall --save angular-cli"');
    }
    if (hasOldDevDep) {
      warnings.push('"npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli"');
    }
    if (hasDep) {
      warnings.push('"npm uninstall --save @angular/cli"')
    }
    if (!hasDevDep) {
      warnings.push('"npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"');
    }
    process.stderr.write(yellow(warnings.join('\n'), '\n\n'));
  }
}

resolve('@angular/cli', { basedir: process.cwd() },
  function (error, projectLocalCli) {
    var cli;
    if (error) {
      // If there is an error, resolve could not find the ng-cli
      // library from a package.json. Instead, include it from a relative
      // path to this script file (which is likely a globally installed
      // npm package). Most common cause for hitting this is `ng new`
      cli = require('../lib/cli');
    } else {
      // Verify that package's version.
      Version.assertPostWebpackVersion();

      // This was run from a global, check local version.
      const globalVersion = new SemVer(packageJson['version']);
      let localVersion;
      let shouldWarn = false;

      try {
        localVersion = _fromPackageJson();
        shouldWarn = localVersion && globalVersion.compare(localVersion) > 0;
      } catch (e) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.error(e);
        shouldWarn = true;
      }

      if (shouldWarn && CliConfig.fromGlobal().get('warnings.versionMismatch')) {
        let warning = yellow(stripIndents`
        Your global Angular CLI version (${globalVersion}) is greater than your local
        version (${localVersion}). The local Angular CLI version is used.

        To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
        `);
        // Don't show warning colorised on `ng completion`
        if (process.argv[2] !== 'completion') {
           // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log(warning);
        } else {
           // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.error(warning);
          process.exit(1);
        }
      }

      // No error implies a projectLocalCli, which will load whatever
      // version of ng-cli you have installed in a local package.json
      cli = require(projectLocalCli);
    }

    if ('default' in cli) {
      cli = cli['default'];
    }

    let standardInput;
    try {
      standardInput = process.stdin;
    } catch (e) {
      delete process.stdin;
      process.stdin = new events.EventEmitter();
      standardInput = process.stdin;
    }

    cli({
      cliArgs: process.argv.slice(2),
      inputStream: standardInput,
      outputStream: process.stdout
    }).then(function (result) {
      process.exit(typeof result === 'object' ? result.exitCode : result);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Have you installed Node.js?

Comment: what does `node -v` and  `npm -v` shows in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

The command should be

> ng new `<project name>.`

Run this command either in node.js command prompt and then import the folder in visual studio code.  Or You can use the integrated terminal from visual studio itself to run it.

Angular cli should be installed and you should be able to get the ng version from command prompt before you can create a project successfully

Comment: My command is, "ng new Colorizer". Which is correct, i'm pretty sure.
Angular cli is also installed with npm install -g @angular/cli.

Comment: When i enter ng, i automatically get the same pop-up. Every ng commands gives it

Answer (score 0):

Please, go to your cmd or terminal (Mac OS x in my case), and run **ng new** followed by the name of the project. For instance:

```
$ ng new my-new-app
```

In this case my-new-app is the name of the folder it will create with all the startup files for Angular.

Hope this helps.